# How to use acast (reshape2) within a function in R?

Tags: r, function, global-variables, local-variables, reshape

I tried to use `acast` from `reshape2` within a self written function, but had the problem that acast did not find the data I send to it.

Here is my data:

```
library("reshape2")
x <- data.frame(1:3, rnorm(3), rnorm(3), rnorm(3))    
colnames(x) <- c("id", "var1", "var2", "var3")
y <-melt(x, id = "id", measure = c("var1", "var2", "var3"))
```

`y` then looks like this:

```
  id variable      value
1  1     var1  0.1560812
2  2     var1  1.0343844
3  3     var1 -1.4157728
4  1     var2  0.8808935
5  2     var2  0.1719239
6  3     var2  0.6723758
7  1     var3 -0.7589631
8  2     var3  1.1325995
9  3     var3 -1.5744876
```

now I can cast it back via `acast`:

```
> acast(y,y[,1] ~ y[,2])
        var1      var2       var3
1  0.1560812 0.8808935 -0.7589631
2  1.0343844 0.1719239  1.1325995
3 -1.4157728 0.6723758 -1.5744876
```

However, when writing a small wrapper for `acast` that should do the same, i get a stupid error messages:

```
wrap.acast <- function(dat, v1 = 1, v2 = 2) {
    out <- acast(dat, dat[,v1] ~ dat[,v2])
    return(out)
}

wrap.acast(y)

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dat' not found
```

The problem is obviously related to something like environments and global/local variables. As it gives other error messages after declaring `dat` in the global environment (i.e., `v1` and `v2` not found as long as they aren't global).

**I would like to use resahpe (especially acast) within a function without the necessity of declaring the variables outside the function. What is the trick?**

Thanks.

Comment: This is a problem that occurs more often lately. I originally found it to be a problem with S4 methods, but apparently it can occur with other functions too. This is supposedly a bug in R, see also the answers on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574858/values-not-being-copied-to-the-next-local-environment/

Comment: Thanks Joris. But now I get the impression that there is no easy solution to my problem. not too nice...

Comment: Just found out there is one actually. It's a matter of correct typecasting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the formula specification, use the character specification:

```
acast(y, list(names(y)[1], names(y)[2]))
```

Comment: That is even simpler. Many thanks. And even more thanks for providing reshape2 and all your great packages!

Answer (score 4):

One issue is that you are abusing the formula notation in R. You shouldn't do things like

```
> acast(y, y[,1] ~ y[,2])
        var1       var2         var3
1  2.1726117  0.6107264  0.291446236
2  0.4755095 -0.9340976 -0.443291873
3 -0.7099464 -1.2536334  0.001105352
```

as the 'y' bits are redundant if a data object is supplied. If you refer to the variables of y by name directly in the formula, things work nicely

```
> acast(y, id ~ variable)
        var1       var2         var3
1  2.1726117  0.6107264  0.291446236
2  0.4755095 -0.9340976 -0.443291873
3 -0.7099464 -1.2536334  0.001105352
```

and the code is much more readable in this second version.

To do what you want using the `acast` wrapper is going to involve generating the correct formula using the `names`, as Joris points out, and Hadley's solution is much simpler. So my point really is to watch out with how you use formula specification in R. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble in the long run (though not specifically with this particular problem) if you use formulas properly.

Answer (score 2):

Correction : problem is not that it doesn't find dat, but that it doesn't find dat[,v1] and dat[,v2] in the specified formula. Acast takes an argument of the type formula, and that one gets evaluated in a temporary environment created around your data frame. Within that environment, it doesn't find a "dat" object when the function is wrapped within another.

I'm not completely following as to how this does work in the global and doesn't when wrapped, but if you feed acast a formula, it does work within a function as well.

```
wrap.acast <- function(dat, v1 = 1, v2 = 2) {
    x1 <- names(dat)[v1]
    x2 <- names(dat)[v2]
    form <- as.formula(paste(x1,"~",x2))
    out <- acast(dat,form)
    return(out)
}
```

using your toy data :

```
> wrap.acast(y)
        var1      var2       var3
1 0.04095337 0.4044572 -0.4532233
2 1.23905358 1.2493187  0.7083557
3 0.72798307 0.7868746  1.7144811
```

Answer (score -2):

I found a pretty inelegant way to solve the problem using super assignments (`<<-`).
Changing the function to the following does the job. But, it is pretty ugly as it creates global variables which remain.

```
wrap.acast <- function(dat, v1 = 1, v2 = 2) {
    dat <<- dat
    v1 <<- v1
    v2 <<- v2
    out <- acast(dat, dat[,v1] ~ dat[,v2])
    return(out)
}
```

I am still very interested in other (less clogging) solutions.

prior to running the function:

```
> ls()
[1] "wrap.acast" "x"          "y"
```

after running the function:

```
> ls()
[1] "dat"        "v1"         "v2"         "wrap.acast" "x"         
[6] "y"
```

Comment: As you noticed yourself, the use of super assignments should be avoided at all times, unless you really want to make a global variable. And even then you might want to rethink the problem...